# How to change (migrate) the character set of a root container database in a multi-tenant architecture?

Tags: oracle

I have at my disposition a multi-tenant database where both the root container database (referred to as CDB from now on) and the pluggable database (referred to as PDB from now on) have been installed with the WE8DEC character set (select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';).

The requirement would be that both (or at least the PDB, which I am actually using) use the AL32UTF8 character set. And installing a new database from scratch is not an option.

In 12.2 character set migration to unicode should be done with the DMU (Database Migration Assistant for Unicode) tool. However, in this particular setup this doesn't help me, because:
- DMU can only be used for PDB's
- and I cannot migrate to unicode a PDB whose CDB is not already in unicode
- but DMU cannot migrate the CDB to unicode

Therefore my question is:

How can I migrate the CDB from WE8DEC to AL32UTF8?
(According to my research, and export/import approach could perhaps come into discussion, but that involves installing from scratch a new database server with AL32UTF8 encoding. But as I said that's not an option in my specific case.)

Has anybody encountered this specific dilemma yet?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: "Installing from scratch a new database server with AL32UTF8 encoding. But as I said that's not an option in my specific case" Yet, that might be your best way to go. Which is why it's VERY important you choose your characterset carefully when creating a database.

Comment: i asked our internationalization support expert to take a look and provide advice, stay tuned

Answer (score 1):

Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU) does not support migrating CDB root. The solution is to create a new CDB in AL32UTF8, move the PDB to it and then use DMU to migrate the PDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeff, for your answers and for comfirming that practically, these no other way and I would need to install a new CDB database from scratch.

Comment: The thing is, I am actually using one of Oracle's official Docker images (container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim), which, unfortunately, has been created/installed with the WE8DEC character set (both the CDB and the PDB). Do you have any idea why Oracle did their Docker image like this, when recently they recommend almost everywhere to use AL32UTF8? Do you think they did it like this on purpose or just didn't think about this?

Comment: @Sorin you can configure that at creation time and the default is Unicode  https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Comment: At https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition?tab=reviews, you can see that someone else has also raised this question (see review of user "mmonge"). So I think this is quite a pertinent question: why wouldn't Oracle's docker database(s) be rather encoded with AL32UTF8? Was this an oversight on the part of Oracle?

Comment: @Sorin i'll find out and get back to you

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. The github link might prove very helpful for putting together my own image with unicode encoding.